# Razor Page Layout.cshtml displaying hidden controls when it shouldn't

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor

I was trying to have items hidden unless a user has access to that section/page.  Everything stays hidden when the initial page is loaded.  The controls in the Layout.cshtml file are in this logic.

```
@if (Context.Request.Cookies.TryGetValue("CookieValue", out string val10) == true)
{
    <a class="nav-link text-white" style="background-color:seagreen;" asp-page="Home Page">Home</a>
}
```

However, when the user logs in, the hidden items display.  The same cookie check for that same value happens on the page load as well, and the appropriate redirect to the landing page happens.  How do I keep the controls from being rendered unless the appropriate value exists?

Answer (score 0):

This condition only judge whether it has the cookie `CookieValue`, and assign the value to val10. But you need to add a external condition to filter the appropriate value.

```
@if (Context.Request.Cookies.TryGetValue("CookieValue", out string val10) == true)
{
      @if (val10 == "value")
       {
           <a class="nav-link text-white" style="background-color:seagreen;" asp-page="Home Page">Home</a>
       }
}
```

Comment: Yep, that worked.  How come it works when the page is initially loaded (the layout.cshtml controls are initially hidden) though?

Comment: And, is there a cleaner/better way to do it?

Comment: @jnelson, if you use `return View()`, it will not render the view. So the controls will be hidden when the page is initially loaded. You have to use `return Redirect()` when use logs in.